# Creating a 3D point cloud from an euclidian Distance Matrix

Tags: python, math, matrix, geometry

I have a huge matrix that came out from a text similarity analysis like

| elem/elem | text1 | text2 | text3 | text4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text1 | 1 | 0.8 | 0.6 | 0.18 |
| text2 | 0.8 | 1 | 0.73 | 0.29 |
| text3 | 0.6 | 0.73 | 1 | 0.6 |
| text4 | 0.18 | 0.29 | 0.6 | 1 |

I want to create a 3D cloud point that represent all my element in a 3D space with the distance between points according to the relative distance to all other elements

I would like to transform my table into something more like this:

```
points=[
{'text1':[x,y,z]},
{'text2':[x,y,z]},
{'text3':[x,y,z]},
{'text4':[x,y,z]},
]
edges=[
[[x,y,z],[x,y,z]],
[[x,y,z],[x,y,z]]
[[x,y,z],[x,y,z]]
[[x,y,z],[x,y,z]]
[[x,y,z],[x,y,z]]
]
```

I will implement the computation in python with numpy and pandas, and the rendering in a vueJS app, with a 3d lib such a D3js.

I'm for now searching for the right algorithmic approach to convert distance matrix into absolute 3D coordinate.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You can't do much better than taking the text index for x and y and the similarity for z.

Comment: yes it wasn't my purpose, x,y and z are computed to match a 3d space where all point respect theyre relative distance to each other. it wasn't a question about x, y as index and z as similarity

Comment: You can't do much better than taking the text index for x and y and the similarity for z.

Comment: i had in mind a more complex mathematical problem solving like taking a first element in [0,0,0] as initial element. then  take a random vector with any direction but with a defined magnitude (aka text similary distance). from there i have 2 points. from there i will for every new point in a loop compute all possibilities where the new point coordonate match the vectorial distance to all connected nodes. your proposal of x,y as index and z as distance, is mathematicaly false for a 3d distance cloud

Comment: You can't create a point cloud with N² imposed distances, this is just impossible. Even very approximately.

Comment: Thnaks i finally went for a force weigthed graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. i finally went for a force weigthed graph